Spring-Boot: Command Line Argument for Deeply Nested Configuration Property
I have a Spring-Boot 3.1.6 application with a rather complex configuration object. In the application.yml there is this:
cfg:
  array:
    - ref-id: 123
      name: special name
      some-key:
        sub-array:
          - value1
          - value2
          - value3

Now I want to overwrite "value1" via command line:
java -jar app.jar --cfg.array[0].some-key.sub-array[0]=valueX

However, it seems as if myCfg.array[0] becomes a completely new object and everything I configured in the configuration file is ignored or removed. Therefore, refId is 0 and name is null.
What am I doing wrong here? How do I correctly set just that nested value while everything else stays as configured in the configuration file?

Spring Boot does not allow this. You need to completely repeat the entire array.
Another approach (but may not match your desire):
cfg:
  array:
    - ref-id: 123
      name: special name
      some-key:
        sub-array:
          - ${editableValue}
          - value2
          - value3

Then use editableValue in command line arguments.

That's sad. Luckily I can use this in my context, only I use - ${editableValue:value1}. -- Welcome to SO :)
